# query from/to, newest within a specific timerange

Tags: sql, hana

I have the following table:

```
PersNumber | Property | From | To
XXX | 34 | 20180101 | 20180630
XXX | 38 | 20180701 | 20190330
XXX | 39 | 20180401 | 20201231
```

I have a period time frame, i.e. from 2018-01-01 to 2019-12-31

I need to query the last row (actually only the 2 first columns). The criteria is actually : from / to within the timerange, and the newest if more than one. Meaning :

1. row : out because not in the period scope
2. row : a part is in the period scope but not the newest
3. row : a part is in the period scope, and this is the newest

I don't know whether the problem is understandable, if not do not hesitate to tell it to me

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Answer (score 1):

You seem to want:

```
select t.*
from t
where date_from >= '2018-01-01' and date_to <= '2019-12-31'
order by date_from
limit 1;
```